# Active image of UV/Image Editor

Tags: python, scripting, uv, image

After creating an image using:

```
bpy.data.images.new(name="NewImage2", width=512, height=512)
```

How would I set that image to the active image within the UV/Image Editor in Python?

[image: Set Image in UV Editor Active?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You loop through area till you find the UV/Image editor and set the active image to you image

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas :
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR' :
            area.spaces.active.image = my_img
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if that space isn't open?

Comment: @user53145 try changing spaces.active to something like spaces["myspace"]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct way to do it. This will work even if the UV Editor pane isn't open:

```
bpy.ops.image.new(name='Some Name')
image = bpy.data.images['Some Name']

bpy.data.screens['UV Editing'].areas[1].spaces[0].image = image
```

Comment: This would only work if you don't change your Blender screen layout at all. @Chebhou's answer is more robust.