# Blender Python: How to get active viewport window?

Tags: python, add-on

I'm making an add-on that does some calculations based on the image you have open in the image editor. Due to the fact that you can have multiple image editors open at a time with different images, it would be great to be able to say "Get image in the current editor."

How would I go about doing this? I'm pretty experienced with python and programming in general, but a complete noob at writing Blender add-ons

Comment: i think there is no "current editor". Only one where the mouse cursor is "over".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Context.area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=context%20area#bpy.context.area) returns the area *in context* (and its attributes). Test using the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html):

```
>>> C.area
bpy.data.screens['Scripting']...Area

>>> C.area.     
           as_pointer(
           bl_rna
           bl_rna_get_subclass(
           ...

>>> C.area.type
'CONSOLE'
```

Get the active space of the *Image Editor* and use [`SpaceImageEditor.image`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.html?highlight=imageeditor#bpy.types.SpaceImageEditor.image) (in this case the same for all spaces). Example based on  the *Operator Simple* template. Run the script, in the *Image Editor* press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type `"Simple Image..."`:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "image.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Image Editor Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR'

    def execute(self, context):
        image = context.area.spaces.active.image
        if image:
            # print (dir(image)) # Print all image attributes
            self.report({'INFO'}, "{}, {}".format(image.name, image.filepath))
        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "No active image")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Related: [Active image of UV/Image Editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/active-image-of-uv-image-editor)